# Error when saving word doc C#

Tags: c#

I currently have a program that merges individual word. documents as selected by the user. The user has 5 input options which allows selection of files. The combine button then calls the MsMerge.cs and combines the files selected into one. Below is an example of the command

```
private void combineButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       List <string> docList = new List<string>();
       docList.Add(selectedFile1);
       docList.Add(selectedFile2);
       docList.Add(selectedFile3);
       docList.Add(selectedFile4);
       docList.Add(selectedFile5);

       if (outputFolder2 != @"")
       {
           loadingForm.Show(); // To show the loading form

       string fileDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
       string fileTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
       string outcomeFolder2 = outputFolder2;
       string outputFile2 = "Combined Files " 
                           + fileDate + " @ " + fileTime + ".docx";
       string outputFileName2 = Path.Combine(outcomeFolder2, outputFile2);

       MsWord.Merge(docList.ToArray(), outputFileName2, true);

       loadingForm.Hide(); // to hide the loading form

       // Message displaying how many files are combined.
       MessageBox.Show("A total of " + docList.Count + " documents have been merged", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
       }
```

the problem I am having is when this 'merge' sequence is finished, I am presented with a "want to save changes to your document" - as if the program isn't correctly saving / combining the files selected. Due to this i think there is a clash between 'List' code shown above and the MsWord.cs,

```
  public class MsWord
{

    private static string defaultWordDocumentTemplate = @"Normal.dot";

    public static void Merge(string[] filesToMerge, string outputFilename, bool insertPageBreaks)
    {
        Merge(filesToMerge, outputFilename, insertPageBreaks, defaultWordDocumentTemplate);
    }

    public static void Merge(string[] filesToMerge, string outputFilename, bool insertPageBreaks, string documentTemplate)
    {
        object defaultTemplate = documentTemplate;
        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
        object pageBreak = Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage;
        object outputFile = outputFilename;

        // Create a new Word application
        Word._Application wordApplication = new Word.Application();

        try
        {
            // Create a new file based on our template
            Word.Document wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(
                                          ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing);

            // Make a Word selection object.
            Word.Selection selection = wordApplication.Selection;

            // Count the number of documents to insert;
            int documentCount = filesToMerge.Length;

            // A counter that signals that we shoudn't insert a page break at the end of document.
            int breakStop = 0;

            // Loop thru each of the Word documents
            foreach (string file in filesToMerge)
            {
                breakStop++;
                // Insert the files to our template
                selection.InsertFile(
                                            file
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing);

                //Do we want page breaks added after each documents?
                if (insertPageBreaks && breakStop != documentCount)
                {
                    selection.InsertBreak(ref pageBreak);
                }
            }

            // Save the document to it's output file.
            wordDocument.SaveAs(
                            ref outputFile
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing);

            // Clean up!
            wordDocument = null;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // need to add handler
        }
        finally
        {
            // Finally, Close our Word application
            wordApplication.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
    }
```

}

I initially had the 'combineButton' rigged up to merge a string [] array as opposed to a list which partially worked as it allowed 5 documents to be combined, however it required all 5 user inputs to be selected. if the user chose 2/3/4 files, the program would crash. This then led me to change my design from String array to a List.

I've been trying to find what is causing the clash but so far have failed to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated

** *update 1*

seem to be getting error 
**Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'** 
when the program throws up the save-as popup.

** *update 2*

program will merge documents in 5 selections are made. If the maximum 5 files are selected, the merge process will work fine, however if 2/3/4 files are selected, leaving vacancies in the selection - the popup error will occur, leading me to think that the vacant browse paths are clashing with the saving process.

Comment: And what is the value of outputFile?

Comment: in the combineButton2? it's just the name of the file being created, which is Combined files + time stamp. this is then path.combined with the output folder the user selects, which is labelled as outputFolder2

Comment: I am talking about this line which (presumably) causes the error; wordDocument.SaveAs( ref outputFile....). Just try to hardcode the full path instead of outputFile and see if it works. Best regards,

Comment: I'd also check Windows permissions on the directory you're trying to save to, and try saving elsewhere.

Comment: @AlexBell - i'm 100% not sure what you mean purely by "hard code" the solution. but i shall mess around and see what i can conjure up. i have a separate button elsewhere that calls the same MsWord (it merges a folder as opposed to separate files) and it works fine. i assumed the list is what caused the clash

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, i've checked the permissions / ran as administator. i just seems very odd that it worked purely as an array but not as a list converted to an array.

Comment: @cgraham720, the `List<string>` -> `string[]` change should not make any difference in this case. The array is never interop'd to Word. It's handled purely in managed code. This is a coincidence I'm afraid. You should look elsewhere.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, so there is no solution? would this be a PC / VStudio issue as opposed to a coding issue then?

Comment: By "hardcode the full path instead of outputFile" I mean to enter the full path typed explicitly, like @"C:\Temp\MyTestFile.doc". Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell -  i will try my best and play around with this. the problem with the static file path is that it isn't a feasible option. The user has to select where they want the file to be saved. I will try to get some sort of solution then hopefully write back with positive news. thank you

Comment: @cgraham720, oh there's definitely a solution. But it wouldn't have anything to do with array vs list difference. Inspect the `COMException` you're getting, get the `HResult` or `ErrorCode` and do some googling or post it here - that'll get you a little closer to solving this.

Comment: I understand that: this is just for testing purpose. If it works then look at the other code parts. Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, it was discovered that if the 5 list items were inserted it worked however 2/3/4 didn't, suggesting that the lack of files was causing a clash. i then added if statements to add the 'docs' to the list if they were not null, meaning it would only merge what was selected as opposed to looking for the 5 supposed files:

```
  private void combineButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var docList = new List<string>();

     // if statements to determine if the file is added
        if (selectedFile1 != null)
        {
            docList.Add(selectedFile1);
        };

        if (selectedFile2 != null)
        {
            docList.Add(selectedFile2);
        };

        if (selectedFile3 != null)
        {
            docList.Add(selectedFile3);
        };

        if (selectedFile4 != null)
        {
            docList.Add(selectedFile4);
        };

        if (selectedFile5 != null)
        {
            docList.Add(selectedFile5);
        };

        string[] docListString = docList.ToArray();

        if (outputFolder2 != @"")
        {
            loadingForm.Show(); // To show the form

        string fileDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
        string fileTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
        string outcomeFolder2 = outputFolder2;
        string outputFile2 = "Combined Files " + fileDate + " @ " + fileTime + ".docx";
        string outputFileName2 = Path.Combine(outcomeFolder2, outputFile2);

        MsWord.Merge(docListString, outputFileName2, true);

        loadingForm.Hide(); // to hide the form

        // Message displaying how many files are combined. 
        MessageBox.Show("The " + docListString.Length.ToString() + " individual Documents selected have been merged", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

the code is abit crude however the basics are all there, just need to clean it up and add additional statements to ensure that more than 1 file must be selected for merging etc.

thank you all for the advice throughout!

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the program to work with no popup errors / save-as errors, purely from trial-and-error

```
private void combineButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var docList = new List<string>();
        docList.Add(selectedFile1);
        docList.Add(selectedFile2);
        docList.Add(selectedFile3);
        docList.Add(selectedFile4);
        docList.Add(selectedFile5);
        string[] docListString = new string[docList.Count];

        if (outputFolder2 != @"")
        {
            loadingForm.Show(); // To show the form

        string fileDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
        string fileTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
        string outcomeFolder2 = outputFolder2;
        string outputFile2 = "Combined Files " + fileDate + " @ " + fileTime + ".docx";
        string outputFileName2 = Path.Combine(outcomeFolder2, outputFile2);

        MsWord.Merge(docListString, outputFileName2, true);
```

essentially i changed the `List docList` to `Var docList` in the button code, i then changed the list back into a string manually as opposed to using the `.ToArray.`

i'm not sure why the previous code didn't work, however there must have been some clash with the list and MsWord.cs to cause the error. Thank you to @AlexBell and @KirillShlenskiy for their suggestions throughout.

Comment: false alarm. program wasn't compiling the documents - thus the error not appearing.

Comment: I'd be surprised if using List was the problem but Array has a resize method. I just figured the code you would need to write to determine which indexes were filled would be more awkward than using a List and calling ToArarry()

Comment: @crowcoder - after some messing around with the code, i've discovered the "popup" message about saving the file as a name only appears when one of the 5 browse files are left blank. if for example i select 5 individual files and combine. the program works. however if i chose 2/3/4, the popup appears. it's as if the lack of doc(s) disrupts the saving process.

Comment: looking at this code you seem to always be adding to the docList 5 times. You only want to Add if the value you are adding is not null. So you need some logic to only add as many selected files as you have so that Count is not always 5.

Comment: @crowcoder - i was actually looking into removing the files from the list if the filepath was null, however your method of adding if the file wasn't null makes much more sense. the program is now working (checked for 2,3,4,5 files) - finally... thank you for the advice. i will add the solution